# MVC core 3.1 conrtoller not receiving form data

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am sending form data to my controller. I can see the form data is populated in Chrome dev tools under the network call. I also have:

```
content-length: 300
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

My mvc controller has a model in the parameter with all the same fields as the formdata using the name upper and lower case names. The signature looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyFunction(MyModel model)
```

The call gets to the controller but the model is always empty. What happened to the data I sent?

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that the model name or object not matched. Can you post the related code about how to send the form data to the controller, using JQuery or submit the form? And, it is better to post the View page source and the MyModel model, it is better for us to reproduce the problem and fix it.

Comment: Im using jquery ajax method, but I already know that it is sending OK because the message in the header section of Chrome Dev tools shows the form data. All the fields are populated and spelled the same as the view model. As well, the form was generated using MVC Core 3.1 and tag helpers. So the model was used to validate the fields as I was typing. I have already checked the model name in both the controller and the view page. One thing that I am thinking may be causing problems is a check field, but I see its data in Chrome as well. I just see both values when its checked

Comment: I have been playing with it more and noticed that I can change the model in the parameter of the controller to anything, even invalid objects and the compiler still will use this action and just not populate the parameter.

Comment: please check the sample code about using JQuery ajax to submit object, if still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following sample works well on my side, you could refer to it:

Model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Code in the view:

```
@model MVCSample.Models.MyModel
 
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="AddMyModel">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input asp-for="IsSelected" class="form-check-input" />
                <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="IsSelected">
                    Selected
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-create" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn-create").click(function () {
            event.preventDefault(); 
            //create a object to store the entered value.
            var MyModel = {};
            //using jquery to get the entered value.
            MyModel.FirstName = $("input[name='FirstName']").val();
            MyModel.LastName = $("input[name='LastName']").val();
            MyModel.IsSelected = $("input[name='IsSelected']").is(":checked");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/AddMyModel",  //remember change the controller to your owns. 
                data: MyModel,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data) 
                }, 
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Code in the controller:

```
    public IActionResult AddMyModel()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddMyModel(MyModel model)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

After clicking the submit button, the result like this:

[image]

If the problem still not solved, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: After looking over my model (multiple times), I noticed that some of my properties were set to read only. ug. I hate obvious stupid mistakes that I make. Your answer somewhat hit on it and I appreciate you taking the time to think about it.